# How to install pgAdmin 4 in server/Desktop mode on Mac?

Tags: install, python, postgresql

How to install pgAdmin 4 on Mac using python wheel. 
I found a help for Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/788457/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-server-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04 but I did n't find anything for mac.

Followed the instruction which is mentioned in the [pgadmin site](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/). But getting the following error

```
Thirumals-MacBook-Air:Downloads Thirumal$ python ~/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py 

python: can't open file '/Users/Thirumal/pgadmin4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you not seen the macOS installers on the [PgAdmin Website](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/) or the wheel installer also located [right beside it](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python-wheel/)?

Comment: There are two different options to do this, using the installer or using the wheel. Both are available, one just fully integrates with the the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed anaconda3 already in system.So pgAdmin 4 takes anaconda3 has default path to install.

```
python /Users/Thirumal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

output:

```
Starting pgAdmin 4. Please navigate to http://127.0.0.1:5050 in your browser.
```

But it's asking for login [image]